# Canvas incorrect measureText()

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord.js, node-canvas

I am making a Discord bot and trying to display someone's level, I would like it to basically say "LEVEL 1" for example, but the distance between the word level and the actual level would change depending on the level they are on. So I am trying to offset the word a little, but when I use measureText(), it displays incorrectly. Code:

```js
    const levelNumber = '1';
    const levelText = 'LEVEL';

    ctx.font = '48px Shapirit';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
    ctx.textAlign = 'right';
    ctx.fillText(levelNumber, 880, 96.8);

    ctx.font = '22px Shapirit';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
    ctx.textAlign = 'right';
    ctx.fillText(levelText, 880 - ctx.measureText(levelNumber).width - 20, 96.8);
```

Here is the current output:
[image: output 1]
[image: output 2]

Comment: I think it's because your changing the font before measuring see this GIST: https://gist.github.com/piecioshka/cce6ea53ba0db1a4700e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @Jay is right. You have to `measureText` with the right font, if not you get the wrong results.

See sample below

```js
function drawLevel(x, y, txt, num, style) {
  ctx.font = '48px Shapirit';
  ctx.fillStyle = style;
  ctx.textAlign = 'right';
  ctx.fillText(num, x, y);
  w = ctx.measureText(num).width

  ctx.font = '22px Shapirit';
  ctx.fillStyle = style;
  ctx.textAlign = 'right';
  ctx.fillText(txt, x - w - 20, y);
}


canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

drawLevel(200, 40, 'LEVEL', '999', '#FF1700');
drawLevel(200, 80, 'LEVEL', '11', '#0000FF');
drawLevel(200, 120, 'LEVEL', '1', '#00FF00');
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I don't suppose you could show me how I would then add two more items offset from level 999? I know I could just run drawLevel again, but they are going to be a different color so not sure how I do it.

Comment: The color is not a big deal I just change the drawLevel to receive a color... what I'm not sure is what you mean by "add two more items offset from level 999" maybe you can ask a separate question and provide a sample image of what you need and what you tried so far

Comment: Adding that color worked perfectly, I will try to explain better as to not open a really similar thread. Basically right now it says 'LEVEL 999' and I want it to say 'RANK 999  LEVEL 999' (but rank will be a different color, which you already solved)

Comment: I think you need to `measureText` of everything you write and adjust accordingly